# append div doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, append, clone

I have a big problem. I'm trying to append a new div but it doesn't work.

My function is:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $meter = $('#analog_meter'), count = 1;
    $('#addanalog').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(count > 2){
            alert("That's enough already!");
            return;
        }
        count ++;

        ($meter.parent()).append($meter.clone());
    });
});
```

And my sample of code to plot my analog meter is:

```
<div id="add" style="visibility:hidden;" style="display:inline-block;"><a id="addanalog" href="#" Onclick="add_new_analog();">ADD NEW ANALOG</a></div>

<div id="plot_analog">
    <div id="analog_meter" name="analog_meter">
        <!-- less information --> 
        <div id="content-two" style="visibility:hidden;">
                <div id="chart1"  class="jqplot-target"></div>
                <a id="div-one" href="#" Onclick="mostra1();"><? echo LABEL_MORE_INFORMATION ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a id="div-two" href="#" Onclick="mostra2();"><? echo LABEL_LESS_INFORMATION ?></a>
        </div>
        <!-- more information -->
        <div id="content-one" style="visibility:hidden;">
            <div id="chart2"  class="jqplot-target"></div>
            <a id="div-one" href="#" Onclick="mostra1();"><? echo LABEL_MORE_INFORMATION ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a id="div-two" href="#" Onclick="mostra2();"><? echo LABEL_LESS_INFORMATION ?></a>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
```

What's happening is that every time I click ADD NEW ANALOG, plots two analog meters.
like this:

what I want is that when click add, plot only one analog meter.

Comment: It's not *the* problem, but this is *a* problem: What you're doing creates an invalid DOM: You're cloning an element that has an `id` (and which has child elements that also have `id`s), but not changing the `id` values before appending the clones to the document. `id` values **must** be unique on the page.

Comment: How can I solve this?

Comment: @ user: ...change the `id`s? Don't have `id`s at all?

Comment: How can i change the id of the divs as long as i am appending new div's? help me please

Comment: @ user: I suggest you step back from your current task and work through some DOM/jQuery tutorials. To remove the `id`s from the cloned elements: `var $clone = $meter.clone(); $clone.find("*").addBack().removeAttr("id");` then use `$clone` when appending.

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing

```
Onclick="add_new_analog();"
```

Seeing as you hook up the click event through jQuery. If add_new_analog() adds an analog, and your jQuery function adds an analog, you end up adding 2.

Edit: @T.J. Crowder has a good point about the ids. You should make sure they stay unique when cloning.

Answer (score 0):

You added **two clickhandlers** to `<a id="addanalog" href="#" Onclick="add_new_analog();">ADD NEW ANALOG</a>`

First by adding the handler in the `onclick` markup and the second in "codebehind" in your JavaScript file:

```
$('#addanalog').click(function(e){   // register second click handler
     e.preventDefault();
     if(count > 2){
        alert("That's enough already!");
        return;
     }
     count ++;

     ($meter.parent()).append($meter.clone());
 });
```

I think the easiest way will be to remove one of them.

Comment: How? i need both. one of them, plot my analog meter. and the other, add more divs...

Comment: ok maybe I did not understand. But what does `add_new_analog();` do. you have not posted the code for this function/constructor/event

Comment: function add_new_analog()
{
 plotmychart(xmlhttp.responseText);

Comment: Stripped you example and added this to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdfYp/1/) for me its working. where is the problem?